# Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: tables, compilation-error

I have problems with the tabular environment, using this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[H]
    \centering

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{
        |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}
        |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}
        |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}
        |}

    \hline
    NO. & Campo & Resultado \\ \hline
    1 & Longitud & 13.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{table} 

  \end{document}
```

Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition. |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}|}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}|}

Comment: Upgrade your TeX system. By the way, the option for ISO A4 paper is `a4paper`, not `a4`.

Comment: the size of the paper is representative because I declare personalized measures, in a template that was programmed more than 3 years ago, this table structure was always used, from a time here the problem has appeared and we have not been able to solve the tables created from this way.

Comment: also replace `H` with `htb` or add the `float` package into preamble. also width of the second column is to small that their content can be fit inside. try rather use `c` columns specifier.

Comment: the float package is added in the template

Comment: do you get the  stated error from the posted document? If so show the log. It should give no error just warnings about the incorrect `a4` option and text being too wide for the column.

Comment: I will correct the heading in the question